# how do I start a memcache server

Tags: php, apache, memcached

I was installing the memcache at this 
[manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-12-04) 
 . But I got a error after

```
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

error

```
localhost [127.0.0.1] 11211 (?) : Connection refused
```

I found several an answer, but they don't work such as

```
/etc/init.d/memcache start | restart
```

Comment: /etc/init.d/memcache status please and which distro?

Comment: bash: /etc/init.d/memcache: No such file or directory.

debian 6

Comment: `ps aux | grep memcache
root     10103  0.0  0.0   7548   872 pts/1    S+   01:36   0:00 grep memcache.` `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 11211` empty

Comment: I think that the question could be moved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install memcache:

```
apt-get install memcached
```

create configuration:

```
vim /etc/memcached.conf

[...]
# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
# -l 12.34.56.78
-l 127.0.0.1
[...]
```

restart service:

```
/etc/init.d/memcache restart
```

check status and listen port:

```
netstat -tap | grep memcached
```

I hope i helped.

Comment: do memcache and memcached different the applications?

Comment: `memcached` is service to store data in memory, `mamcache` is client to data manage.